# VBA Excel excluding one sheet when saving PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I am fighting with the exclusion one sheet, that I don't want to be saved as my PDF file.

My code comes from the query formed here:

[How to exclude 1 sheet from my save to pdf VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283670/how-to-exclude-1-sheet-from-my-save-to-pdf-vba-macro)

and it looks as follows:

```
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Readme").Visible = xlSheetHidden

 ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select

 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
 ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

 Sheets("Frontsheet").Select

 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Readme").Visible = xlSheetVisible
```

Basically between my PDF saving code I plot the code for sheet hide.

In the effect one of my sheets is hidden, but I am getting an error at the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select` line

> **Method 'Select' of object 'Sheets' failed.**

If I  change the place of my code like this:

```
Sub DPPtoPDF()

  ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select

  Sheets("Readme").Visible = False

  ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
  ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name, _
  Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
  IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

  Sheets("Readme").Visible = True
  Sheets("Frontsheet").Select
```

Then I can save only 1 page instead of the whole docum,ent without this sheet.

Could anoyne tell me what's going on here?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047183/select-all-visible-worksheets-to-print-to-pdf) may be helpful. Or if you know exactly what sheets are to be printed, you can include them in an array and then only select those. The error is because you can't select a hidden sheet.

Comment: Well - from the question you linked to, it looks like you want [`Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat) if you hide the sheet... not `Worksheet`. So I'd say this question is a duplicate of the one you linked to, in a way; you just need to implement the PDF creation as done in the linked question.

Comment: I changed it, but it says, that variable is not defined. When I put ThisWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat, then I am getting the same error.

Comment: Get rid of the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select` line entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27283670/how-to-exclude-1-sheet-from-my-save-to-pdf-vba-macro) you linked to, note that the PDF creation uses [`Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat), not [`Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat).

The error is occurring because you can't select a hidden worksheet, but you don't need to select here at all.

Remove the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select`, and then use `ThisWorkbook` instead of `ActiveSheet`.

I would also double check your filename... `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name` is equivalent to `ThisWorkbook.FullName`, but make sure it doesn't include the extension (.xlsm), and I would also include the `.pdf`.